# R data.table key and secondary indexes compatibility

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to use both keys and secondary indexes on some data tables.
In the doc and in the [indexes vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-secondary-indices-and-auto-indexing.html) I do not find any warnings about them being alternative, I only find that there can be just one key, that should not necessarily imply incompatibility.

This is the behaviour I get:

```
require(data.table)

keys <- c("a","b","c")
d <- data.table(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)

# set key ok
setkeyv(d,keys); print(key(d))
## [1] "a" "b" "c"

# indexes seem to fail when key is present
setindexv(d,keys); print(indices(d))
## NULL

# without key indexes work  
d <- data.table(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
setindexv(d,keys); print(indices(d))
## [1] "a__b__c"
```

I would need help to understand whether my understanding or code is wrong or whether key and secondary indexes are actually not compatible.

Comment: Thanks for letting me notice about >
You are right, using different sets of key columns it seems to work, so your comment answers my question, they are compatible and an "optimization" provides the output that perplexed me. If you move it to an answer I can accept it

Comment: Ok, cool. Fyi, if you think it should be done differently, you could make an example and leave a note for the package devs following their instructions here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setindexv` redirects to `setkeyv`, which has a step like...

> ```
> else if (identical(head(key(x), length(cols)), cols)) {
>     setattr(x, "sorted", cols)
>     return(invisible(x))
> }
> ```

This causes the code to exit before the step where it would add to indices. I think the reasoning is that it is redundant to have an index `a, b, c` whenever the data is already marked as sorted by `a, b, c, d, e`.